# What exactly can concrete domains be used to describe?

Tags: logic

I have read the formal definition of a "concrete domain", but I still don't quite get it.

Could someone explain it to me in simpler terms, preferably with some examples?

The definition is available in
[*Reasoning in Description Logics with a Concrete Domain in the Framework of Resolution*](http://www.fzi.de/KCMS/kcms_file.php?action=link&id=403) by Ullrich Hustadt, Boris Motik, Ulrike Sattler. Page 1, Definition 1.

Comment: Links to those formal definitions that you claim to have read would be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good with the predicate logic myself but became intrigued by your question so I read up and got a fairly good overview of the concept of concrete domains from the part 6.2.1 in "The Description Logic Handbook", it had some examples also.

I'm a new user and can't post links but you will find the book by searching for "concrete domains" on Google (look for books.google.com).

I hope it helps, I found the formal definition hard to get as well! The beginning of part 6.2.1 is good for introduction in the book.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get it COMPLETELY, but the info in the book was helpful. Buuut, I think I'll still leave the question open ;)